# Choosing a convergent sub-sequence from a sequence of bi-Lipschitz homeomorphisms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be two compact metric spaces. Suppose there is a sequence of bi-Lipschitz homeomorphisms $f_n: X\to Y$, and $c\in(0,1]$, satisfying 
$$c\cdot d(x_1,x_2)\le d(f(x_1),f(x_2))\le \frac{1}{c}\cdot d(x_1,x_2),$$
for any $x_1,x_2\in X$.

Is is true that one can choose a sub-sequence $f_{n_i}$ that uniformly converges to a bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism $f$ (with the same constant $c$)?

Such a statement would imply that in case the Lipschitz distance between two compact metric spaces is bounded, it is actually realised by a bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism (which is better than taking an inf over all bi-Lipschitz homeomorphisms).

Comment: This should follow from an appropriate version of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem for maps between metric spaces.  Even if you haven't seen such a version, it would be a good exercise to adapt the proof for real-valued functions.

Comment: Yes: all you need is a subsequence that converges uniformly (or even just pointwise). The fact that the limit function must be bi-Lipschitz is easy.

Comment: Dear Nate and Nik, I guess you are right. I wonder though why the proof of Theorem 7.2.4 in Burago, Burago, Ivanov http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.368.3775&rep=rep1&type=pdf doesn't use this fact. It is a tiny bit more involved than that. This theorem states, in particular, that two compact metric spaces on Lipschitz distance $0$ from each other are isometric.

Comment: @aglearner That's a striking application ! Did not see that at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a subsequence $\,g_n\,$ of $\,f_n\,$ which is uniformly convergent. Then consider a subsequence $\,h_n\,$ of $\,g_n\,$  such that sequence $\,h^{-1}_n\,$ is uniformly convergent. Then the limit function $\,h\,$ of $\,h_n\,$ is bilipschitz with the bi-constant equal the same $\,c.$   ***Great***

> ***REMARK*** This proves what @NikWeaver has already said in his comment under the OP's *Question*. (Yes, I agree with the comment by @NatEldredge).

Comment: Note that the result also holds not assuming that the $f_n$ are homeomorphisms and in this case, you cannot use $h_n^{-1}$. The $f_n$ certainly are one-to-one but necessarily onto in general. However, you don't need to play this trick to obtain a bi-Lipschitz limit. Since $g_n$ converges pointwise (note that this is enough) to a limit $g$, fixing $x_1$ and $x_2$, you get $1/c d(x_1,x_2)\leq d(g_n(x_1),g_n(x_2))\leq c d(x_1,x_2)$ for every $n$, so that the same holds with $g$.

Comment: @aglearner Actually the answer proves that and I think that's the point of the answer (although not explicitely stated). Denote by $g$ the limit of $g_n$ and by $h$ the limite of $h_n^{-1}$. Then, $h_n$ also converges to $g$. Also, $h_n \circ h_n^{-1}$ converges pointwise to $Id$ and converges pointwise to $g\circ h$, so that $g\circ h=Id$. Similarly, $h\circ g=Id$. Since both $g$ and $h$ are Lipschitz, they are in particular continuous and so they are inverse homeomorphism.

Comment: You are right M. Dus, thanks!

Comment: @Dirk, did I say "bilinear"? :) === seriously, thank you Dirk for the correction.